# Why didn't Moses and his siblings ask to be buried in Israel?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, moshe-rabbeinu, funeral-burial-levaya, miriam, aharon

It appears that the merit of being buried in the Holy Land of Israel is huge and our forefathers, as well as numerous prominent Rabbis, demanded to be buried here.

Why didn't Moses, Aharon and Miriam ask for that? (At least, why does the Torah not tell anything about it?)

Comment: Who says that they did not ask. Moshe for example, wanted to be buried in Eretz Yisrael and Hashem said no.

Comment: @sabbahillel Where do you learn it from? AFAIK, Moses wanted to enter the promised land, but he didn't argue about being carried into it just as he carried Yosef's bones.

Comment: I was basing it on the idea that he was willing to enter the land even if he died immediately.

Comment: @sabbahillel So at least he could enter it post-mortem